# Triggering a cmd on HDMI plug-in

Tags: hdmi

I would like the following command to run each time I plug in my HDMI monitor:

> ## Swap monitor outputs
>
> xrandr --output eDP-1 --right-of HDMI-1

Answer (score 1):

Found an easier fix for what I wanted, here: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html